# Is there a javascript tree that expands upwards?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree to show a regular tree that expands downwards

[image]

I was wondering if there is any tree that can be used (or midfield version of the jstree) that expands the other way. Upwards!

Something like:

[image]

With obviously texts shown the right way. Not upside down.

Comment: I somehow found that mirrored image funny. I mean you could always just add `transform: scaleX(-1);` to the CSS...

Comment: @JCOC611 and then the text is upside down... But to answer the question, it doesn't seem like there is, but you can always write one (it will be weird).

Comment: @Shahar: Actually, if you use `transform: scaleY(-1);` on both the parent element and every child, it would rotate it twice, creating the desired effect.

Comment: Smart suggestion @JCOC611!